# Confused with Sprite Kit's bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath coordinate system

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have this image as an SKSpriteNode:

[image]

Dimensions of this image are 394px X 347px.

later in the code, I am adding physics body with bodyWithPolygonFromPath function over this SKSpriteNode with image.

The path I have given is:

```
CGMutablePathRef shipPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(shipPath, NULL, 0,0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(shipPath, NULL, 0,347);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(shipPath, NULL, 394, 347);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(shipPath, NULL, 394, 0);

CGPathCloseSubpath(shipPath);
```

This path should exactly trace a physics path in form of square around the spaceship image to detect the collusion for rocks falling from above.

This is the program output:
[image]

Next screenshot explains the problem:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? I hope I have explained the problem well.

Comment: Have you tried checking the anchor point? I believe by default it is in the center of the sprite

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. Anchor point is in the center of the sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SpriteKit, the sprites have a default coordinate system where (0, 0) is the center, although the SKScene has a default coordinate system where (0,0) is the lower left corner. You can change this by adjusting the Sprite's `anchorPoint` property.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how can I set SKSpriteNode's anchorpoint to center as well? It seems to be on lower left corner. Because of that, animation seems out of sync.

Comment: don't change anchorPoint, change the body's path so its center is at 0,0

Answer (score 1):

After having a look into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath%3a):

```
+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:(CGPathRef)path
```

> **path** - A Core Graphics path. The points are specified relative to the
>   **owning node’s origin**. The path must not intersect itself.

The origin in the `SKNode` is defined by its anchorPoint which by default is `(0.5, 0.5)` which is center of the node.

**Why is it center?**

The texture of the sprite is drawn relative to the node position based on the `anchorPoint` factor. It's default value of `(0.5, 0.5)` places the texture centered on the node's position.

You might want to adjust the anchor point, but it will change the position of the texture which you don't want. Instead, adjust your path when creating the physics body.

It is different for `SKScene` though. For `SKScene`, the default value is `(0, 0)`, which corresponds to the lower-left corner of the view’s frame rectangle. To change to center specify `(0.5, 0.5)`.

Based on: [SKPhysicsBody Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath%3a), [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and [SKScene Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)